# Bitbucket email commit diffs of large repositories

Tags: git, bitbucket, webhooks

I'm running a small webhook service (for personal use) which can email commit diffs to users. The idea is to clone the repo on the server, get the commit details, and then send the diffs by some email sender.

However, my coming project is of quite large size (~100 MB), and the little server is a bit overwhelmed to clone the repo on each push. So my question is that, is there any existing Bitbucket- internal or external email diff service?

I know GitLab still has this feature, but we prefer to keep all our projects together and unmoved. It would be great if we can mirror the repo from GitLab and push commits to GitLab repo, but that feature is only for GitLab enterprise version.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: One clone is enough and later you could run `git fetch` to update the repository. The work tree is not necessary for generating diffs so it can be a bare clone.

Comment: @ElpieKay It's a good idea. I'll update my script in this way while waiting for  other available tools. Thanks!

Comment: See the Bitbucket restful api, https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/diff/%7Bspec%7D.